# T1D autoimmunity causes' possibilities

Tags: autoimmune, diabetes-mellitus

As far as I've learned about T1D, the prevalence of the disease and autoimmune disorders in general over the past 5 decades intrigued me to the point it made me wonder if it's really a genetic predisposition. I've read that it could be related to a virus but as far as I've read and came to conclude, could it be the EBV virus in the first place as a primary suspect infecting the beta cells in those with no genetic hisory of diabetes in their families?

1. I learned that EBV infects the human body then morphs itself into a human cell look-alike, could it be why the immune system attacks beta-cells if EBV infected them?
2. I also learned that there is a significant population with islets' antibodies present in serum yet over the years they never develop T1D and they stay within perfect glycemic control.

My question is, were there any studies done to examine that EBV possibility being the cause of T1D and if there were any studies done to explain why some of those with islets antibodies never go through the T1D autoimmune storm?